# I want to display the elements of "Gig posts" depending on which user is logged in

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is how I structured the my data

[image]

I can get the current user - curtUser, and the id for each of the gig posts. I've tried using different methods like .child("users").child(curtUser).child("Gig posts") but I'm getting a lot of errors that states the viewholder cannot display the elements of desserts which is the name, description, firstletter and ammount.

```
            final String curtUserId;
            DatabaseReference mDatabaseGig, databaseGig;
            FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
            FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;

            mFirebaseAuth= FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            FirebaseUser currUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            curtUserId = currUser.getUid();

            mDatabaseGig = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("/users/" + curtUserId + "/Gig posts/");
            final String id = mDatabaseGig.push().getKey();
            final List<Dessert> dessertList;

            dessertList = new ArrayList<>();
           final DessertAdapter adapter = new DessertAdapter(getContext(), dessertList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            mDatabaseGig.addValueEventListener(new com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    dessertList.clear();
                    for(DataSnapshot gigSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        Users user = new Users();
                        Dessert dessert = dataSnapshot
                                .child(id)
                                .getValue(Dessert.class);
                        dessertList.add(dessert);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get those values, please use the following code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference gigPostsRef = rootRef.child("users").child(uid).child("Gig posts");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String amount = ds.child("amount").getValue(String.class);
            String description = ds.child("description").getValue(String.class);
            String firstLetter = ds.child("firstLetter").getValue(String.class);
            String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", amount + " / " + description + " / " + firstLetter + " / " + name);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
gigPostsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Your output will be:

```
40 / is gone / M /mai
10 / i need someone to take notes for me / T / TAKE NOTES
```

Comment: THANKS. I'm trying to "get" the values on a string, I'm trying to save them to as an object then display it on a recycler view .

Comment: If  you have a model class, the you can get the data as an object of the class. If not, use the data to create a new object of the class and use it in your RecylerView.

Comment: here is my current error 'Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.gig.Model.Dessert.getName()' on a null object reference
                                                                             at com.example.gig.Adapter.DessertAdapter.onBindViewHolder(DessertAdapter.java:65)
                                                                             at com.example.gig.Adapter.DessertAdapter.onBindViewHolder(DessertAdapter.java:21)'

Comment: here is the line for DessertaAdapter.java.65 
       holder.mName.setText(dessert.getName()); and for line 2= public class DessertAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DessertAdapter.DessertVh>

Comment: I do have a model class called Dessert. Here is my implementation of getting the data as an object of the class 'public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    dessertList.clear();
                    for(DataSnapshot gigSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        Dessert dessert = gigSnapshot
                                //.child(id)
                                .getValue(Dessert.class);
                        dessertList.add(dessert);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();'

Comment: 'Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.gig.Model.Dessert.getName()' on a null object reference means that your object is `null`. Check that object to return the correct value and not null. Does my above code work?

Comment: It works, thanks. But I need the data to be saved as a whole object that has name, amount, description elements - which I already created i.e the desserts object, not as separate string entities. I have debugged it and I think something is wrong with my adapter class. Here's the link to the question I posted about it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47978270/null-pointer-exception-on-null-object-reference